# PythonでCSVファイルをDict型およびlist型で読み込みたい

Tags: python, python3, csv

Python初心者のため、無礼な質問かも知れませんがご教示ください。

Pythonで以下のようなcsvファイルからデータを読み込む方法を考えています。

**CSV**

```
A C D T
1,7 0 0 2
2,7 0 0 3
3,7 0 0 5
4,7 0 0 2
5,7 0 0 3
6,7 0 0 5
0,1 8 10 2
0,2 70 15 3
0,3 9 10 5
0,5 5 10 2
1,2 10 15 3
1,3 90 10 5
2,3 120 10 2
2,4 85 15 3
3,4 7 15 5
5,4 150 15 2
5,6 11 15 3
6,2 140 15 5
6,4 130 15 2
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上の画像のように読み込ませることを目標にしています。
CSVファイルから列を指定して、1列目のみをlist型に、１列目のタプルと２列目をDict型、１列目のタプルと３列目をDict型、１列目のタプルと４列目をDict型、で読み込ませようと実装してみたのですが、上手くできませんでした。

**Python**

```
import csv

A=[]
C={}
D={}
T={}

with open('/Users/data.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    next(r)
    A=[tuple(map(int,line)) for line in r]

    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        C[tuple([int(s) for s in row[1].split(',')])] = int(row['C'])
        D[tuple([int(s) for s in row[1].split(',')])] = int(row['D'])
        T[tuple([int(s) for s in row[1].split(',')])] = int(row['T'])
```

CSVファイルはカンマ区切りと空白区切りで作成しています。
カンマ以外は特にこだわり等はなく、他にこの方が使いやすい等ありましたら、ご指摘いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

提示されたコードをベースに A C D T を求めるコード

```
import csv

A=[]
C={}
D={}
T={}

with open('/Users/data.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    next(r)
    for line in r:
        key = tuple(map(int, (val for val in line[0].split(','))))
        A += [key]
        C[key] = int(line[1])
        D[key] = int(line[2])
        T[key] = int(line[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

以下は pandas を利用する方法です。

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', engine='python', sep='[, ]', skiprows=1, header=None)
>>> A = list(zip(df[0], df[1]))
>>> C, D, T = [dict(zip(A, df[i])) for i in range(2, df.shape[1])]

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(A)
[(1, 7),
 (2, 7),
 (3, 7),
 (4, 7),
 (5, 7),
 (6, 7),
      :

>>> pprint(C, sort_dicts=False)
{(1, 7): 0,
 (2, 7): 0,
 (3, 7): 0,
 (4, 7): 0,
 (5, 7): 0,
 (6, 7): 0,
 (0, 1): 8,
 (0, 2): 70,
 (0, 3): 9,
 (0, 5): 5,
      :

>>> pprint(D, sort_dicts=False)
{(1, 7): 0,
 (2, 7): 0,
 (3, 7): 0,
 (4, 7): 0,
 (5, 7): 0,
 (6, 7): 0,
 (0, 1): 10,
 (0, 2): 15,
 (0, 3): 10,
 (0, 5): 10,
      :

>>> pprint(T, sort_dicts=False)
{(1, 7): 2,
 (2, 7): 3,
 (3, 7): 5,
 (4, 7): 2,
 (5, 7): 3,
 (6, 7): 5,
 (0, 1): 2,
 (0, 2): 3,
 (0, 3): 5,
 (0, 5): 2,
      :
```